# Installing pip for arcpy

Tags: python, pip, arcpy

I'm attempting to install pip for arcpy (arcgis 10.2 on windows 7). Running get-pip.py results in the following error message:

```
X:\python>python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20061, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "c:\temp\tmpou5fje\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "c:\temp\tmpou5fje\pip.zip\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "c:\temp\tmpou5fje\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
  File "c:\temp\tmpou5fje\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>
  File "c:\temp\tmpou5fje\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 373, in Specifier
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Using an administrator command prompt doesn't help. My real goal is to get win32com working under arcpy. I usual just copy the appropriate directories out of c:\python27\lib\site-packages to c:\python27\arcgis10.2\lib\site-packages to install a package under arcpy (why doesn't arcpy come with pip?) but that's not working for win32com, presumably do to a missing dll or other windows specific file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. Get the `setuptools` module
2. Get the `pip` module`

And then run the following in command line (assuming windows)

`path-to-python path-to-setuptools install`

`path-to-python path-to-pip install`

I work on a closed network (away from the interwebs of old) and cannot use `get-pip.py` so I find it best to simply download the actual modules and hard install.

Keep us posted!

Answer (score 0):

Copy `get_pip.py` to "`C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2`", then perform command "`python get-pip.py`" in the directory.
Note that keep network connected in the process, so that auto-download and setup setuptools,wheels,etc.
Hope that can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening a CMD prompt and typing:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe -m pip install -U pip
```